# Angular - I want the background of the body/html to change (transition slowly) to a random color when clicking a specific button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can I change the CSS styling of a different object than the one that is clicked.  Also, how can I animate it?  I can do this using jQuery but not with Angular.  Note: I have a list of colors and a $scope.randomColor that is a Math.random of that array.

Here is a jQuery example of what I want the page to do: [link](http://codepen.io/alexanderdd/full/jrPEMR/).

```
<div class="question-text">
  <h2>Home Page</h2>
  Do you want to know the best country to travel to for your budget, tastes, and preferences?<br />
  <button ui-sref="q1" ng-click="changeColor()">Let's Get Started</button>
</div>
```

in controller:

```
  var colors = ['#FF4D63', '#3848AC', '#513584', '#9D4075', '#4D7AFF', '#875EEF', '#525561'];

  $scope.changeColor = function() {
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    document.getElementByClass(".question-text").style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
  };
```

I'm also getting this error on the click:TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function
    at r.$scope.changeColor

Comment: Show us what you've achieved so far

Comment: correct function is `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

Got it changing the body:

```
  var colors = ['#FF4D63', '#3848AC', '#513584', '#9D4075', '#4D7AFF', '#875EEF', '#525561'];
  var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  var pageColor = document.body;
  console.log(pageColor);

  var changeColor = function() {
    console.log(randomColor);
    pageColor.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
    console.log("got here");
  };

  changeColor();
```

but now, it can only affect the "body" of the page that is within the controller, so below the divs that are in my corresponding HTML template for each controller, the color does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You could try do something like:

```
<div class="question-text" ng-style="{'background-color':activeColor}">
    <h2>Home Page</h2> 
    Do you want to know the best country to travel to for your budget, tastes, and preferences?<br />
    <button ui-sref="q1" ng-click="changeColor()">Let's Get Started</button>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var colors = ['#FF4D63', '#3848AC', '#513584', '#9D4075', '#4D7AFF', '#875EEF', '#525561'];
  $scope.activeColor = 'inherit';
  $scope.changeColor = function() {
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $scope.activeColor = randomColor;
  };
```

Then you animate with css:

```
.question-text {
    transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mollwe/p7zckj56/1/

I think you should avoid using document and select elements if you can. Angular is not jQuery.